# Why does IRS Stimulus Tracking Tool Claims “Payment Status Not Available” When I Am Eligible? AND I paid my taxes by check, not through Turbotax

Tags: irs

I am in the same situation as many others, my adjusted gross income was less than 75000 in 2018, not a dependent, etc, AND I paid my taxes in 2018 by check, NOT through the tax application. Why am I getting this error? I was hoping I could input direct deposit information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the logic behind the IRS direct deposit of the stimulus check?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/124031/what-is-the-logic-behind-the-irs-direct-deposit-of-the-stimulus-check)

Comment: I got this message yesterday but it works correctly for me now. I think they're just having issues due to volume, try it again tomorrow.

Comment: I just asked the same question yesterday - https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/124129/why-does-irs-stimulus-tracking-tool-claims-payment-status-not-available-when-i?noredirect=1&lq=1 - it appears they might need to process paper checks for those that paid 2018 taxes as opposed to received a refund.